# CSS - Resizing the width of the window suddenly causes white space between divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs overlapping each other on a website I'm building.  One is a looping video and another is a simple box with text in it.

With my window at full screen, the div with text will overlap onto the video as intended, but when I make the width of the screen smaller the div is suddenly pushed downwards off the video, causing a blank area in between the two.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code for the video positioning: 
`

```
 position: absolute;
    top: 44%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
```

`

And here is the css for the other div positioning: 
`

```
min-height: 900px;
min-width: 10em;
height: 900px;
z-index: 3;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 55em; 
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
overflow: hidden;
```

`

If this helps, in the HTML, the video and this div are not in the same container and there are several other divs in between the two in the HTML file.

Comment: In body{} for CSS I also set width/height to 100%, if that has any effect on this

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide an example to look at and play with, e.g. on jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: add jsfiddle or codepen demo